# Unable to build iOS from command line after creating the platforms directory, requires opening xcode manually

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

## The short version

If I don't currently have a platforms/ios folder, and I run:

```
cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios --buildConfig=build-scripts/uat/ios-build.json --device --release
```

I get this error if I'm not an admin for our project in Apple Developer:

```
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.n.uuat' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.n.uuat' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS In House provisioning profiles matching 'com.n.uuat'.}
```

How can we build ios from the command line this way?

Same error in Xcode:

[image]

## The long version

We're doing this because we have to be able to build our projects headlessly.

Also, we need to be able to switch between prod, uat, and qa environments. For prod if we use use com.n.u, then for uat we'd use com.n.uuat, for qa we'd use com.n.uqa. If you try to switch these app id's without remaking the platforms directory, it causes issues.

So our build scripts delete the platforms directory before each build.

This issue only occurs if the developer building is not an admin on developer.apple.com. As soon as we promote them to admin, they can build fine. We don't want to have to make everyone an admin though.

### Important settings we're using

- Automatic Signing
- In House Distribution

### The ios-build.json file

```
{
  "ios": {
    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "...redacted",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "packageType": "enterprise",
      "automaticProvisioning": true,
      "buildFlag": [
        "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.n.uuat",
        "PRODUCT_NAME=UUAT",
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note that if we log in to xcode with an admin account, build it, the log out and back in with a non admin account, it works. But, we don't want to do that for every identifier and every app.

Comment: Correction: Opening it and building in Xcode does NOT work with Automatic, but it does work with Manual.